# Доступ к проекту по ip

Tags: linux, golang

Разрабатываю проект на языке программирования goland,  на  Windows  запускаю(по  адресу localhost:3000) все работает. Теперь надо этот  проект  перенести на  внутренний  сервер  предприятия,  поставил  на  сервер  Red Hat 7.5  и  БД  mysql. Проект  запустился,  все  работает,  тоже  по  пути  localhost:3000. Теперь  хочу  подключится из другого компьютера по  ip адресу,  вводя айпи сервера:3000,  и  ничего  не  происходит. Кто то  сталкивался с такой  проблемой,  как ее можно  решить?

Comment: за'`bind`'и сокет к нужному адресу, или `INADDR_ANY` (aka `0.0.0.0`), чтобы слушать на всех интерфейсах, затем посмотри `netstat -tln`, что он слушает на верном порту + если есть огнестенка, но открой на ней порт... я не знаю синтаксис/api/макросы в go, чтобы дать конкретный код... по крайней мере без [mcve] в вопросе.

Comment: Странно  еще  то,  что  в остальных  сборках убунту  получалось  все  нормально,  просто  запускал  проет,  вводил  айпи и порт и проект  работал, а на ред хате  не хочет

Answer (score 0):

Если ip адрес находится вне локальной сети надо на роутере делать проброс порта на локальный ip адрес